# manually creating new blocks with Babe

Tags: grandpa, babe, block

Currently my consensus engine is Babe, and my finality gadget is Grandpa.
But for testing environments I'm wondering if that there is a way to manually force the engine to produce a new block when I request.

Is there a way to implement this? or is it impossible for now?

Answer (score 2):

One requirement of Babe is to produce at least one block per epoch.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4464#issuecomment-567651962

You could create a "test" runtime with [instant seal](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/consensus/manual-seal) to achieve the result you desire.

Here are couple implementations of instant seal:

- https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/commit/e018d429c027a0e95bd504dd7204881ba1c8d7b2
- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/pull/42/files